# Retrieve return value of a Javascript function in the WebBrowser control in vb6

Tags: vb6, webbrowser-control

I have a vb6 application,

I make a function call with WebBrowser script but I need to get the return value of that function

my current function is

```
v = WebBrowser1.Document.parentWindow("v = function(){return callOther();};v()");
```

Then, i need the v value.. the posible value is javascript function.

How to retrieve "v", my test response with Error 91 (Object variable with block variable no set).. i'm beginner with vb6.

Comment: Related question: [How to retrive form value using execScript in VB6?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15798908/588306)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Assign return value of your JavaScript function to JavaScript variable.
2. Use `execScript` method of `WebBrowser.Document.ParentWindow` to
   call your JavaScript code.
3. Now retrieve value of the variable via
   `WebBrowser.Document.Script.<JavaScript variable name, case-sensitive>`
   in VB6.

   ```
   Private Sub cmdJsFunc_Click()
       Dim retVal As String

       Call WebBrowser1.Document.parentWindow.execScript("v = function(){return 3.14;}; tempJsVar=v();")
       retVal = WebBrowser1.Document.Script.tempJsVar

       MsgBox retVal
   End Sub
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
Set v = WebBrowser1.Document.parentWindow("v = function(){return callOther();};v()")
```