# How to retrive form value using execScript in VB6?

Tags: vb6

Say, this is my code

> Dim Address as string
>
> WebBrowser1.Document.parentWindow.execScript("var a =
> document.form1.address.text", "JavaScript")

how can i extract the value of `document.form1.address.text` to my VB6 variable  `Address`?

Comment: Related question: [Retrieve return value of a Javascript function in the WebBrowser control in vb6](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9005914/588306)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use DOM.

Let us say we have simple HTML form:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form name="form1">
        Address: <input type="text" id="address">
    </form> 
</body>
</html>
```

After loading it in a `WebBrowser` control and making sure DOM is ready, we can get text of `address` field in the following way:

```
Private Sub cmdGetAddressText_Click()
    Dim HTMLElement As Object
    Dim Address As String

    Set HTMLElement = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementByID("address")
    Address = HTMLElement.Value

    MsgBox Address
End Sub
```

**Edit:**

It's even simpler than that. You can access field value directly from VB6:

```
Address = WebBrowser1.Document.Form1.Address.Value
```

**Edit#2**

It is also possible to get a value of a JavaScript variable if you wish to do so:

```
Private Sub cmdJSVar_Click()
    Dim Address As String
    Call WebBrowser1.Document.parentWindow.execScript("var a=document.form1.address.value; alert(a);")
    Address = WebBrowser1.Document.Script.a

    MsgBox Address
End Sub
```

Notice that JS variable name in `.Script.a` is case-sensitive (i.e. `.Script.A` won't work). It took some time to figure this out.

Comment: If global namespace state persists script execution, than this explanation is a much much better approach than my navigation hack.

Answer (score 2):

You can provide an `IDispatch` implementation to `window.external` but this is not easy to do VB6.

Easier would be to use `location` in JS to navigate to an address that you can capture in `Navigate` event in VB6 e.g. `http://callback?param=value&param2=anothervalue`, detect "callback" host, parse the parameters and cancel navigation.