# How to find and call javascript method from vba

Tags: javascript, vba

I believe I need to call a javascript method instead of trying to fire buttons. I have tried the following examples and I think my problem is that I don't know which parts of the code I should use..[Click button or execute JavaScript function with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247391/click-button-or-execute-javascript-function-with-vba) and this http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?9690-Solved-call-a-javascript-function and http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?650771-RESOLVED-How-to-Call-a-JavaScript-function-From-Visual-Basic-6-WITH-wanted-parameters

I can't post a link because it requires a login to access it... Please let me know if you need a larger sample of the code to make sense of my question.

I believe I need a function that references "Export as CSV" but I am not sure which function to call and which parts of function to include in the call... The following is from catalog.js

```js
  function()
  {var a=window.Ext4||window.Ext;a.define    ("Rally.alm.ui.page.plugins.PageToolFactory",{singleton:true,mixins:    {messageable:Rally.Messageable},PRINT:"PRINT",IMPORT:"IMPORT",EXPORT:"EXPORT",ge    t:function(c,b)
{var d=[];
if(this._shouldHaveRowAction(this.PRINT,c))
{
if(b.getPlugin("printplugin"))
{
d.push({text:"Print...",handler:b.getPlugin("printplugin").print,cls:"page-    tools",scope:b.getPlugin("printplugin"),addInteractionClass:true})}}
if(this._shouldHaveRowAction(this.IMPORT,c))
{
if(b.getPlugin("printplugin"))
{
d.push({text:"Import User Stories...",handler:a.emptyFn})}}
if(this._shouldHaveRowAction(this.EXPORT,c))
 {
    if(b.getPlugin("printplugin"))
                  {
                              d.push({text:"Export as  CSV",handler:a.emptyFn})}}                                                                return d}
```

This next sample is from yui.js...

```js
 (function()
 {
 RALLY.ui.menu.AvailablePageTools=Ext.extend(Object, {constructor:function()
 {
 this.PRINT={text:'Print...',slug:'print'};
 this.EMAIL={text:'Email...',slug:'email'};
 this.SAVE={text:'Save...',slug:'save'};
 this.CSV_IMPORT={text:'Import User Stories...',slug:'csvimport'};
 this.CSV_IMPORT_PORTFOLIO_ITEM={text:'Import Portfolio    Items...',slug:'csvimport'};
 this.CSV_EXPORT={text:'Export as CSV',slug:'csvexport'};
 this.PDF_EXPORT={text:'Export as PDF',slug:'pdfexport'};
```

I have tried these options in my vba script..

```vb
Dim objIE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer 'microsoft internet controls   (shdocvw.dll)
Dim htmlDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument 'Microsoft HTML Object Library
Dim htmlInput As MSHTML.HTMLInputElement
Dim htmlColl As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim CurrentWindow As HTMLWindowProxy




'Set objIE = Nothing
Set objIE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate


With objIE

   .navigate "website"
    .Visible = 1
    Do While .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

    Set htmlDoc = .document

    objIE.document.all.Item
        'Set CurrentWindow = objIE.htmlDoc.parentWindow
        'no error no export
        'Call objIE.document.parentWindow.execScript("_exportHandler:Function()", "JavaScript")

         'no error no export
        'Call objIE.document.parentWindow.execScript("_getExportItems:Function()", "JavaScript")

        'RUN TIME ERROR could not complete the operation due to error 80020101 (error while evaluating js)
        'Call objIE.document.parentWindow.execScript("_a.define()", "JavaScript")

        'run time error the object invoked has disconnected from its clients,
        'RUN TIME ERROR could not complete the operation due to error 80020101 (error while evaluating js)
        'Call objIE.document.parentWindow.execScript("_b.push()", "JavaScript")

        'run time error the object invoked has disconnected from its clients,
        'RUN TIME ERROR could not complete the operation due to error 80020101 (error while evaluating js)
         'Call objIE.document.parentWindow.execScript("handler:function(){window.location=Rally.ui.grid.GridExport.buildCsvExportUrl(this.gridboard.getGridOrBoard())}", "JavaScript")

        'Call objIE.document.parentWindow.execScript("b.push()", "JavaScript")

        'Call objIE.document.parentWindow.execScript("c.push()", "JavaScript")

        'RUN TIME ERROR could not complete the operation due to error 80020101 (error while evaluating js)
        'Call objIE.document.parentWindow.execScript("this.CSV_Export()", "JavaScript")

        'error the remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable
        'Call objIE.document.parentWindow.execScript("constructor:function()", "JavaScript")

        'Call objIE.document.parentWindow.execScript("constructor:function()", "JavaScript")

        'object
        Call CurrentWindow.execScript("d.push({text:CHR(34)Export as CSV CHR(34),handler:a.emptyFn})")

        'ofile.SaveAs scrapeRally:=ofile.Name
       'ofile.Close savechanges:=False

        'objIE.Quit
        Set objIE = Nothing

 End With

 End Sub
```

I am trying to run this from VBA so I couldnt use var...

```
Dim getFunction = "get:function (_shouldhaverowaction(this.export,C)),(b.getPlugin(chr(34)printplugin chr(34)))" 

Dim exportNow 
eval ("exportNow = new" + getFunction + ";")
```

And I also tried

```
Call objIE.HTMLDocument.eval("get:function (_shouldhaverowaction(this.export,C)),(b.getPlugin( chr(34) printplugin chr(34)))", "JavaScript")
```

I got "The object doesnt support this property or method" error when I tried to run it.

Any suggestions would be really great.

I just came across another function that could be the one I want but I still don't know what part of it I should use to call. I tried to call just _getExportItems:function() but I get RUN TIME ERROR could not complete the operation due to error 80020101 (error while evaluating js)

```
 _getExportItems:function(){
 var b=[];
 if(this.enableCsvExport){
b.push({
text:"Export to CSV...",
handler:function(){
window.location=Rally.ui.grid.GridExport.buildCsvExportUrl   (this.gridboard.getGridOrBoard())},scope:this})}
```

Comment: ```execScript``` is no longer supported. Starting with Internet Explorer 11, use [eval](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536420%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Hi Dee I followed your link and tried these two things.. I am trying to run this from VBA so I couldnt use var...   'Dim getFunction = "get:function (_shouldhaverowaction(this.export,C)),(b.getPlugin(chr(34)printplugin chr(34)))"
    'Dim exportNow   'eval ("exportNow = new" + getFunction + ";")                   **AND I ALSO TRIED**       Call objIE.HTMLDocument.eval("get:function (_shouldhaverowaction(this.export,C)),(b.getPlugin( chr(34) printplugin chr(34)))", "JavaScript")     I GOT THE OBJECT DOESNT SUPPORT THIS PROPERTY OR METHOD ERROR..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here simple example which uses `execScript` method of the `window` object. It calls a global functions named `myFunc` and `myFuncWithParams`. *Code was tested with IE 11.*

```
Option Explicit

Private Const Url As String = "c:\Temp\evalExample.html"

Public Sub Test()
    Dim objIE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim currentWindow As HTMLWindowProxy

    Set objIE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    objIE.navigate Url
    objIE.Visible = 1

    Do While objIE.readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Set currentWindow = objIE.document.parentWindow

    ' Here the function without parameters is called.
    currentWindow.execScript code:="myFunc()"

    ' Here the function with parameters is called.
    ' First parameter is numeric, then string, then boolean and finally object.
    ' The object has three properties, numeric, string and array.
    currentWindow.execScript code:="myFuncWithParams(123, 'Some text', true, { property1: 555, property2: 'hi there from object', property3: [111,222,333] })"

    ' And here function which receives parameters and returns value.
    ' The return value is then available through hidden property of document named 'Script'.
    ' Thanks to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005914/retrieve-return-value-of-a-javascript-function-in-the-webbrowser-control-in-vb6
    currentWindow.execScript code:="func = function(){return myFuncReturns(2,3);}; retVal = func();"
    Dim result As Long
    result = objIE.document.Script.retVal
    Debug.Print result ' for 2 and 3 prints 5

    objIE.Quit
    Set objIE = Nothing
 End Sub
```

> evalExample.html

```
<!-- saved from url=(0016)http://localhost -->
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunc() {
            var date = new Date();
            alert("Hi from my parameter-less 'myFunc'. Day of the month: " + date.getDate());
        }

        function myFuncWithParams(a, b, c, d) {
            var number = a + 100,
                text = b + " from my func2",
                bool = !c,
                obj = d;

            var alertText = "\nNumber = '" + number + "'" +
                            "\nText = '" + text + "'" +
                            "\nBoolean = '" + bool + "'" +
                            "\nObject.property1 = '" + obj.property1 + "'" +
                            "\nObject.property2 = '" + obj.property2 + "'" +
                            "\nObject.property3.lenght = '" + obj.property3.length + "'" + 
                            "\nObject.property3[2] = '" + obj.property3[2] + "'";

            alert("Hi from my 'myFunc2' with parameters.\n" + alertText);
        }

        function myFuncReturns(a, b) {
            return a + b;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>eval test</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Dee thank you for your help! I am in over my head for sure, please excuse the dumb questions... For the second code snippet, is that supposed to represent my website sourcecode I am referring to? Or am I supposed to incorporate that somewhere in my vba script?

Comment: Dee the site I am trying to code vba against has several js files. Should I refer to one of them specifically to call the function I need? Thank you!

Comment: This is just an example (very basic one) how to call a java-script function with the ```execScript``` method. In your case you have to find the name of the java-script function you need to execute and use this name instead of 'myFunc()'.

Comment: I have plugged in all the functions I thought that might be what I want but I still haven't been successful... In your example, you call the function without parameters included. Can you include/should you include the parameters when you call js function from vba script?

Comment: I have edited the answer and added a second function with parameters and how to call this function from VBA. Maybe [Getting Started with the F12 Developer Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589500(v=vs.85).aspx) might help you to find the right java-script function.

Comment: @dee Do you know how to return a value from execScript?