# How To Click On Web Page Image Link?

Tags: excel, vba, image, click

I tried several different methods to select a radio button or click on the image. There is an onclick task that is to be triggered. I can't automate any further until this opens up.

```vb
Sub AirCan()
    Dim HTMLInput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim HTMLButtons As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim HTMLButton As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim img As MSHTML.HTMLImg
    On Error GoTo Err_Clear
    MyURL = "https://XXXXXXXXXX.com/en/XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
    MyBrowser.Silent = True
    MyBrowser.navigate MyURL
    MyBrowser.Visible = True
    Do
    Loop Until MyBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Set HTMLDoc = MyBrowser.document
    HTMLDoc.all.paymentAmount.Value = "111" 'Enter your email id here
    HTMLDoc.all.groupPayment.click
    Do While MyBrowser.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        DoEvents 
    Loop 

    Set allInputs = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("img")
    For Each element In allInputs
        If element.getAttribute("src") = "/HPPDP/hpp/images/ca_visa.png" Then
            element.click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Err_Clear:
    If Err <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        Resume Next
    End If
End Sub
```

CODE from the website, clicking the radio button or any of the 3 images will do what I need,

Comment: It's hard to tell when scraping websites.  Are you sure the desired action is triggered by clicking on the .png image and not a DIV or some other object on the web page?

Comment: If the link has a `onclick` function then try `execScript` the function (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31521205/how-to-find-and-call-javascript-method-from-vba)) Without access to the URL and/or snippet of the relevant HTML code, it's hard to help you.

Comment: <div class="paytype_div" style="white-space: nowrap;">
   <input name="payment_type" class="choice_radio" id="cc_radio" onclick="displayPayment('hppFinancialCC')" type="radio" value="cc">   <label class="choice_label" for="cc_radio"><img style="top: 9px; position: relative;" alt="Visa" src="/HPPDP/hpp/images/ca_visa.png"> <img style="top: 9px; position: relative;" alt="Mastercard" src="/HPPDP/hpp/images/ca_mc.png"> <img style="top: 9px; position: relative;" alt="American Express" src="/HPPDP/hpp/images/ca_amex.png"> </label></div>