# 'Object doesn't support this property or method' error in VBA when using IE reference library to execute JS (MS Excel)

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, internet-explorer

I am trying to execute some JS code inside my excel workbook, so I found out about the Internet Explorer & Microsoft HTML references, and I built this code with some inspiration from https://stackoverflow.com/a/31532085 -

```
Dim hf As Integer: hf = FreeFile
Dim data As String

Open "C:\Users\karti\Desktop\3CD-MRL v4 testing\test.json" For Input As #hf
    data = Input$(LOF(hf), #hf)
Close #hf

Debug.Print data
' json data received from file, now sending it to the js code

Dim objIE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim currentWindow As HTMLWindowProxy
Dim Url As String: Url = "C:\Users\karti\Desktop\3CD-MRL v4 testing\test.html"
Dim codez As String: codez = "func = function(){return myFuncReturns('" & data & "');}; retVal = func();"
Set objIE = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
objIE.navigate Url
objIE.Visible = 0

Do While objIE.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

Set currentWindow = objIE.document.parentWindow

currentWindow.execScript code:=codez
Dim result As Long
result = objIE.document.Script.retVal 'here i am supposed to get the updated json
Debug.Print result
objIE.Quit
Set objIE = Nothing
```

and here's my `test.html` file's code (which is set to the `URL` variable in VBA code) -

```
<!-- saved from url=(0016)http://localhost -->
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFuncReturns(json) {
            let jsonObject = JSON.parse(json);
            jsonObject["status"] = "done";
            return JSON.stringify(jsonObject);
        }
    </script>
</head>
</html>
```

---

My JS code is very simple, receive json in string, convert to object, add a parameter named status to the json, re-convert updated object to string, and return the string json to vba. In my VBA code, I just read data from a local json file, send it to my html file using IE reference, and receive updated json string into the `result` variable - but I am getting 'Runtime error 438 - Object doesn't support this property or method' error and this gets highlighted, with `result=0` showing in debugger -

[image]

What's wrong with my code? What should I do? Kindly guide... Thanks! :)

---

**Edit:** Just for debugging, I removed `return JSON...;` from JS and made it into an alert with `alert(...);` and also temporarily removed the `result = ...` line from VBA (as it has no use with an alert). And it works! I received a popup on my screen containing the updated JSON after running the macro. It means that my VBA code is sending the data, it's just not receiving it into the `result` variable. What could be wrong?

Comment: Your code looks like it is just trying to update JSON, correct? I would recommend using the [VBA-JSON](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) code that is on GitHub. This code will Parse JSON and convert back to JSON as well.

Comment: @RobertTodar Thanks for replying! Just for the sake of asking this question I shortened my code - sorry about that. Actually my code takes the json, converts it into xml and is supposed to send the xml string back - I have all JS side figured out, just can't get the string back into the result variable. For now I just want to simply check if I receive the updated JSON - if it works, I'll complete my script for the xml conversion... _(also I have added some more details to question - please check)_ Thanks again! :)

Comment: As far as I know, JSON.stringify(obj) returns a json string, but I found that you define a variable of type Long to receive the returned result, could this be the cause of the problem?

Comment: Hi, @XudongPeng! Thanks for replying - I tried defining as `String`, `Object`, & `Variant`, but nothing works, still the same 'Object doesn't support this property or method' error, with `result=""` coming in debugging when defined as String, `result=Empty` when def. as Variant, and `result=Nothing` coming when def. as Object. What should I do? Kindly guide... Thanks again!